# Diagonal Matrix Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Could someone check if the solution of the problem is right?

Problem:

> Let $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be selfadjoint ,such that $[A,B] := 
> AB − BA = 0$
> Show that there is a unitary matrix  $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such
> that $U^*$A$U$ and $U^*$$B$$U$ are both diagonal.

Solution:

> Let $D$1 =$U^*$A$U$ and $D$2 =$U^*$$B$$U$ .
>
> As $A$ and $B$ are selfadjoint follows that $D^*$=$(U^*$$A$$U)^*$= $U^*$$A$$U$=$D$1, so $D$1 is hermitian, which also  means that $D$1 must be diagonal ?

Comment: No it's wrong. you don't have the same $U$ for $A$ and $B$ in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not right. You started your solution by saying “Let $D_1=U^*AU$”, without saying what $U$ is.

Comment: In the problem is written that U is a unitray matrix.

Comment: @Kai The problem asks you to find such unitary $U$.

Comment: @ xbh Ahh. I am very confused about  the way  of how this problem is defined. Do you think that then I should prove that if U*AU is a diagonal then U is a unitary matrix?

Comment: @Kai No. What you are supposed to prove is that there is an unitary matrix $U$ such that both matrices $U^*AU$ and $U^*BU$ are diagonal.